# Must fluid flows be infinitely smooth inside the domain?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

Let me quickly sketch a derivation of the continuity equation, most of which you can skip through if you are familiar. And I am neglecting the boundary.

Consider two parallel faces of a cube length $\Delta x$, oriented so they are normal to a 1 dimensional flow. We can calculate the net change of a quantity bound in the cube by knowing its flux through both surfaces. So the normal flux from one side plus the normal flux from the other equals the change per unit time of the quantity in the gap (all other faces contribute nothing by construction). There are now four possibilities for the fluxes: both point left, both point right, both point inwards, both point outwards.

**(You can skip to next break if you don't need the derivation which consider both fluxes pointing left or right, i.e., the fluid flows and passes through the volume)**

---

If both point left or right, then the flow passes and continues through the cube, perhaps building up or depleting the quantity. Note that right and left are equivalent as we can perform a proper rotation around an axis perpendicular to the flow to make a left net flow become a right net flow. Therefore, it is always possible to pick a coordinate system with a rightward moving flow. Call the left edge, $x_0$, and the right edge, $x_0 + \Delta x$. We then find the volumetric rate of change in the cube to be

\begin{equation}
\textrm{rate of change} = -\frac{\textrm{Flux}(x_0+\Delta x) - \textrm{Flux}(x_0)}{\Delta x}.
\end{equation}

You divide by the length of the cube because the quantity we are tracking is the density if we are not integrating over the volume. Thus by summing fluxes we are finding the rate of change per cross sectional area, and we can divide by the length to get volumetric rate of change. Again the minus sign is to note that the larger flux leave through the right edge ($x_0+\Delta x$) than coming in from the left edge ($x_0$) is a negative rate of change in the quantity inside the cube, in our rightward moving flow frame.

In the limit of an infinitesimal cube, $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$, we retrieve the definition of a derivative

\begin{equation}
-\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\textrm{Flux}(x_0+\Delta x) - \textrm{Flux}(x_0)}{\Delta x} = -\frac{\partial (\textrm{Flux})}{\partial x}.
\end{equation}

It is not hard to convince yourself that when we restricted the flow to be 1d we took the flux component perpendicular to the face of the flow. Therefore in a higher dimensional problem you simply repeat the procedure for each dimension, and sum all the changes together. This is operationally equivalent to the divergence of the flux. Thus for some quantity $q$ with Flux = $q\vec{u}$, we have arrived at

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial q}{\partial t} + \vec{\nabla} \cdot \left( q \vec{u} \right) = 0.
\end{equation}

**Resume question**

---

Note however we completely ignored two cases; when the fluxes are both moving inwards or outwards. This also means within our volume the velocity is either discontinuous or vanishes, since it goes from negative to positive. These must be handled with care for if we look back at the derivative definition if both are moving inwards or outwards than the fluxes do not subtract. Meaning for inward and outward flowing fluxes

\begin{equation}
\textrm{rate of change} = \pm \frac{\textrm{Flux}(x_0+\Delta x) + \textrm{Flux}(x_0)}{\Delta x}.
\end{equation}

Where the minus is for outward flowing and the plus is for inward flowing. While this is permissible at the finite level, the rate of change goes to infinity in the limit of $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$, unless the flux at each edge also "rapidly'' goes to zero.

Unless I am missing something does this mean we require something special about the velocity field of a flow. I'm thinking that it must be $C^\infty$, so that the fluxes go to zero "rapidly'' as you approach the zero velocity, and equivalently disallows for a discontinuity in the flow.

I realize there are sink and source terms which would have the property of discontinuities, but those terms are not properties of the velocity field.

Answer (score 0):

Flux is a vector quantity and signs are taken care of automatically. So the **only** correct way of writing the net flux into an small volume of space is $F(x+\Delta x)-F(x)$, where $F$ is positive if it is directed along +x direction and negative otherwise.

Comment: The flux is dotted with the normal of the surface. By convention a volume normal points outwards. If you have flux going both in or out then the signs are the same. This also makes sense physically as the flux dotted with the normal talks about the loss rate, so two outward fluxes have positive values means means you are losing mass from both faces. Add both rates from the faces (positive or negative depending on their projection) and you get the loss rate for that volume. As I noted in the section I said you can skip this is only the case for when fluid flows in one side and out the other.